# Text randomly won't get refreshed in graphics mode 13h

Tags: assembly, x86-16, qemu, bootloader

I'm writing a game in assembly and today I noticed strange issue where text displayed at the bottom of the screen in `0x13` graphics mode sometimes won't get refreshed. After some time of searching, I managed to reproduce the problem in much a shorter program, which simply continuously
prints colorful numbers.

My code:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]

;Stack setup
mov bp, 0xffff
mov sp, bp

;Switch into mode 13h
mov ah, 0x00
mov al, 0x13
int 0x10

drawloop:
    ;Set cursor position
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    mov dh, 24
    mov dl, 1
    int 0x10

    ;Load counter into al
    ;Change color to cnt value
    ;Print at page 0
    mov al, [cnt]
    mov bl, al
    mov bh, 0

    ;Print hex value of cnt (low byte)
    call puthexb

    ;Wait 1/18.2 s
    mov ax, 0
    int 0x1a
    mov bx, dx
    delay:
        int 0x1a
        cmp bx, dx
        je delay

    ;Increment counter
    inc word [cnt]

    ;Issue doesn't happen if screen isn't cleared
    call gfxcls
    jmp drawloop

jmp $

cnt: dw 0

;Clear screen
gfxcls:
    pushf
    pusha
    push es
    mov ax, 0xA000  ;Make es point video memory
    mov es, ax  ;
    mov cx, 32000   ;We will write 32000 times (word each time)
    mov di, 0   ;Start at the beginning of the vmem
    mov ax, 0   ;Fill it with 0s
    cld     ;Clear direction flag
    rep stosw   ;Kinda memset
    pop es
    popa
    popf
    ret

;Print contents of al register on screen (as hex number)
;al - value
puthexb:
    pushf
    pusha
    push ax
    and ax, 0x00f0      ;Fetch older 4 bits
    shr ax, 4       ;Shift them into lower position
    mov si, puthexb_assoc   ;
    add si, ax      ;Add offset to assoc table address
    mov al, [si]        ;Print character
    mov ah, 0xe     ;
    int 0x10        ;
    pop ax          ;Restore initial value to display
    and ax, 0x000f      ;Get 4 younger bits
    mov si, puthexb_assoc   ;
    add si, ax      ;Add offset to assoc table address
    mov al, [si]        ;Print character
    mov ah, 0xe     ;
    int 0x10        ;
    popa
    popf
    ret
    puthexb_assoc: db '0123456789abcdef'

times 510 - ( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I assemble and run the code with this command:

```
nasm -f bin vgack.asm -o vgack.bin && qemu-system-i386 -boot a -fda vgack.bin
```

After running for some time, the text stops changing, but the program keeps executing (you can easily check that by drawing color pixel somewhere at the screen each loop iteration) - that's weird.

Problem appears when text is drawn **in the same place each time** and major part of screen is modified (here - cleared, in case of my game - filled with second video buffer contents) between subsequent draws.

Also, the error hasn't yet occurred on a real PC - the program is running on my laptop for approximately an hour now. The problem only exists in qemu (my version is `1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14` - it looks pretty old, but `apt` says it's the newest). So, is there a possibility, that I've found a bug?

---

#### Update

It turns out that the whole line gets redrawn as it was (or not redrawn at all). When background is cleared to different colors, such effect can appear: 
[image]

Comment: The code *looks* ok, but I don't get how you see the text gets not refreshed, when you clear whole screen every time (for me "not refreshed" = "old graphic stays on screen"). If it would be just black-out for short period, that may be due to BIOS palette, the default one for 13h mode had few last colours set to black, but then it looks like the code wraps around and starts again from 0, so it should be ok.  ... But I don't want to run or debug qemu bootloader code (I sort of wonder why not DOS .com/exe instead => more emus, more tools), so I did just read the source.

Comment: BTW, not related to your problem, but set `sp` rather to aligned value, i.e. `0xFFFE` in this case.

Comment: @Ped7g, maybe "not refreshed" wasn't in fact the best term to describe that, but at least that's what it seems. In this case, the whole line gets redrawn as it was before for some reason. I'm running this in qemu, because my game is bootable from floppy and I wanted to remain in the same environment I was testing it in. Also, thanks for the stack tip.

Comment: And finally... how long does it take to that error to happen usually? I modified it to run under DOS as .COM file, and ran it under dosbox, and so far it runs flawlessly, as expected (about 2 minutes of runtime).  ("not refreshed" looks like accurate description of what is happening, but I'm willing to admit this is qemu bug, or maybe its natural deficiency in emulation).

Comment: It still hasn't happened on my laptop (second run, lasting ~15 minutes so far), but in qemu it usually takes less than a minute

Comment: now over 8 minutes in dosbox without any problem (dosbox is of reasonable quality, not fully accurate emulation, but robust enough to run most of the DOS games without any problems, so if it works in dosbox, it's very likely ready for real PC ... qemu vs bootloaders is different story, actually you are sort of lucky such trivial bootloader works on your real PC, as it doesn't have any fixes for the common bootloader problems, and qemu gives you quite "pristine" state after power on, so many real world problems remain undetected until you hit your first weird BIOS PC combo...

Comment: I can reproduce unusual behavior such as this as a bootloader under QEMU. It seems after a number of iterations it seemingly doesn't update the display.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that this simulation may not me 100% accurate and that's why I suppose that may be some kind of bug. Anyway, the more I think about it, the more willing I am to display the text as graphics all by myself and avoid similar or worse problems on other PCs.

Comment: Could be some sort of virtual BIOS issue. What happens if you use `-vga cirrus` as a parameter to qemu ?

Comment: Of course writing directly to VRAM and avoiding BIOS is crucial due to performance reasons... well, it *WAS* crucial back on 386 and 486 machines, but that's not excuse for poor emulation by qemu. And also you will probably want rather to synchronize your main loop to vertical retrace (like VSYNC=on in modern games), as the 18.2Hz will look choppy on 60Hz display. But as far as I can tell your code is correct (not optimal, in the 286 era you would regret those `pusha/popa` soon, if you would use them everywhere, etc... but *correct* it is and should work).

Comment: @Ped7g It's a sokoban game so I suppose vsync isn't crucial in this case, but that sounds like a good idea anyway. I know, that this code isn't optimized at all, but it's just a proof of concept. I used the `pusha`/`popa` to isolate these two routines as much as possible from rest of the code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I added the `-vga cirrus` and after few minutes I cannot see the issue appear.

Comment: After all, it looks like it's a issue with qemu. Do you think it may be worth reporting?